# Find and replace using Listbox Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listbox

ok have a list of 84000 words , and have some articles in these articles i want to replace first occurrence of each word i have in listbox e.g

```
  For Each item In ListBox1.Items
    Dim mytext As String = "My some text this text is very long text and i want to replace this"
    If ListBox1.Items.Contains(mytext) Then
        mytext = Replace(mytext, mytext, "String to replace",Count:=1)
    End If
Next
```

but it used to replace the whole mytext i want to replace words in mytext and also it hang the system and very very slow and help or idea please

Comment: May want to thread or Background Work it to keep the system from hanging.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to replace everything with the same string, but the code below is easily adaptable to other cases but I go with it for now.

To simplify I am assuming that you want to replace words and the words are only seperated by spaces (' ').

First make a dictionary out of the Items in the listbox:

```
dim dict = ListBox1.Items.Cast(of object).ToDictionary(function(x) x.ToString())
```

Then get yourself all words:

```
dim words = mytext.Split(New [Char](){" "c});
```

and a word-transform:

```
dim replaceWith = "your replacement";
dim mapWords as Func(of string,string) = _
   function(word) IIf(dict.ContainsKey(word), replaceWith, word)
```

then transform the words and concatenate them again with ' ':

```
dim result = String.Join(" ", words.Select(function(word) mapWords(word)))
```

and you should be done.

If you want to replace with separate words just make the dictionaries values your replacement and switch the mapWords-function with

```
dim mapWords as Func(of string,string) = _
   function(word) IIf(dict.ContainsKey(word), dict(word), word)
```

Comment: oops - sorry it's C# ... one moment

Comment: I hope I got the vb.net syntax right ... it's quite a pain with lambdas and char-arrays

Comment: thanks for youe help bro but i did not realy understand this method because many properties like ToDictionary is not working for me, i can use an mdb instead of listbox, i there is any idea with this please?

Comment: Hi - ToDictionary is a Extension-Method in the Enumerable-Module - you should import System.Linq to use it - see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277.aspx

Comment: The problem might be that Listbox.Items is only a IEnumerable ... I don't know what kind of objects you wrote there but I will insert a Cast

Comment: @user934820, for future reference if you come across C# code you can use just go here http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/ to convert it.